# Receiving DTMF tone from a call in android

Tags: android, dtmf

I am developing an android application where I want to make use of DTMF tones over a active call. I want to send and receive DTMF tones when I make a call through my android application. DTMF tone will be send over a call through a button click. Then on a same call session I want to receive DTMF tone sent by another user (not necessary android mobile, it can be regular device also). On receiving DTMF tones I want to decode them and execute required functions in application.

Can anybody know how to do this send DTMF tone over a active call and receive the tone from same call to decode it.

Comment: Your question is kind of broad. Making the tones should be easy. The lazy way would be to just record existing tones and replay them. The second part of the question involves sound analysis. You should try using Google. There are libraries for that purpose. You just need to search for them.